# Почему в кодировке число всегда меньше на 1?

Tags: javascript

Например: 32-разрядные (4-байтовые) целые числа со знаком в диапазоне от -2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647.
А должно получиться 2 147 483 648.
Да даже Двоичное 8-ми разрядное число со знаком в дополнительном коде может представлять любое целое в диапазоне от −128 до +127.
Почему не до +128?
Объясните, пожалуйста, простым языком.
Спасибо.

Comment: Потому что отсчёт с нуля

Comment: Вопросы на понимание: Сколько возможно различных значений у восьми бит? Сколько всего целых чисел в диапазоне -128…127?

Comment: В диапазоне *[-X, X]* всего *2X + 1* чисел. Нечётное количество. Восемь бит одного байта или 32 бита могут дать *2^8* или *2^32* различных комбинаций. Чётное количество. Чётность не совпадает. Поэтому, как не придумывай кодировку, число положительных и отрицательных чисел в ней будет различно. Хотя существуют кодировки в которых два нуля (так называемый "отрицательный ноль"). В них диапазон симметричный. Но от двух нулей столько хлопот, что никто не хочет связываться.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том что знак кодируется старшим битом.
Если 0, то это положительное число, если 1 - то отрицательное.
И при этом отрицательные числа задаются в "инверсии".
Если рассматривать случай с 8 битами, то

**00000001** это +1 - т.е. первый ноль говорит о том что это положительное число. А дальше семь битов задают само число. А с помощью 7 битов можно задать самое большое число - это 127. Т.е. почему верхняя граница +127 прояснилось.

С отрицательными числами чуть по другому.

**11111111** это -1 - первая единичка это признак знака. А вот дальше само число. Почему так, а не **10000001**? Для упрощения арифметики.

Компьютер оперирует двоичными числами. И **11111111**+**00000001** даст 0. Потому что перенос разряда пройдет до самого конца и в байте окажется 0. Т.е. с точки зрения процессора просто происходит операция с обычнуми числами. Процессор про знак ничего не знает.

И в таком варианте получается, что самое большое (по модулю) отрицательное число это **10000000** т.е. -128

Comment: Отличное объяснение!

Answer (score 2):

#### Все дело в 0

Диапазон 1 байтного (8 битного) числа может содержать в себе 2^8, то есть 256 цифр. И поскольку 256 четное число то разделяя на 2 группы (положительные и отрицательные) получаем 128 цифр в каждом. Но с -128 до +128 содержит не 256 а 257 чисел, так как внедряет в себе ещё 0. Поэтому создатели ЯП решили чтобы было от -128 до 127. Они так же могли бы поставить от -127 до 128, но от -128 до 128 никак!

Comment: а как кодируется -128? 10000000? типа знаковый бит считается за бит числа? поэтому получается - 128?

Comment: Знаковый бит работает до 127, где 127 будет _1111111. Впереди будет стоять 0, показывая что число положительное, а при отрицательных числах впереди стоит 1. 128 будет уже занимать 2 байта.